# Не записываются все данные в БД SQLite Python

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://balusha.ru/catalog/categories/kolyaski-progulochnye/?display=list'
data = requests.get(url).text
block = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
heads = block.find_all('div', class_='list_item_wrapp item_wrap item item-parent clearfix bordered box-shadow js-notice-block')
# print(heads[0].find_next('a', class_='dark_link js-notice-block__title').find('span').text.strip())
print(len(heads))
for i in heads:
    w = i.find_next('a', class_='dark_link js-notice-block__title').find('span')
    print(w.text.strip())
    nazvan = (w.text.strip())
    artt = i.find_next('div', class_='article_block muted font_sxs')
    print(artt.text.strip())
    articul = (artt.text.strip())
    price = i.find('span', class_='price_value')
    print(price.text.strip())
    cena = (price.text.strip())
    nalich = i.find_next('span', class_='value font_sxs')
    print(nalich.text.strip())
    nalichiye = (nalich.text.strip())

import sqlite3 as sq

from parsing_to_db import nazvan, cena, nalichiye


zonn = sq.connect('students.db')
z = zonn.cursor()
# z.execute("""
# CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS scoons (
# title TEXT,
# numm INTEGER,
# nalichiye TEXT
# )
# """)

z.execute(f"INSERT INTO scoons VALUES('{nazvan}', '{cena}', '{nalichiye}')")
zonn.commit()
zonn.close()
```

Не записываются все данные результата парсинга в БД SQLite. Записывается только одна последняя строка. Если кто знает подскажите почему?

Comment: Ну ведь у Вас и есть один набор из трех данных, он и записывается. Остальные только выводятся на экран.  Проще всего вызвать `z.execute(f"INSERT INTO scoons VALUES('{nazvan}', '{cena}', '{nalichiye}')")` внутри цикла `for i in heads:`. Либо собрать все данные в таблицу (список) и вызвать `z.executemany("INSERT INTO scoons VALUES(?, ?, ?)", all_data_in_list_3xN)`.

Comment: Спасибо!!! Всё работает.